# Lock-free loop with JButton

Tags: java, com, jframe, arduino, jbutton

I'm learning how to interfere with Arduino with help of COM and Java. As COM library I use jSSC. I have a question about receiving data from COM by pushing some JButton in my frame. As I release the button I should start a loop getting data from COM, which gets values every 25 ms. Just some floats.

How can I break this loop by pressing another JButton. For instance, we have two of them: Get data from COM and Stop. First should launch the loop, second - break it.

Maybe you can recommend some better solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach to this would be to do the long running task in a `SwingWorker`.  Call [`cancel(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#cancel%28boolean%29) if the 'stop' button is activated.